# Sorting a CSV file using key words inside of a column

Tags: python, csv, sorting

I am trying to use Python to group transactions on a bank statement. The transactions are listed in a CSV file. I can't get it to use a portion of the description instead of the entire description.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work because it uses the entire description. (i.e. AMZN MKTP 09/01 PURCHASE) which is too specific. I want it to only use "AMZN" to sort.

```
grouped = test.groupby(['Description'])
for key, item in grouped:
    print('Key is: ' + str(key))
    print(str(item), '\n\n')
```

Below is a sample of the data in the CSV file.

08/15/2022, AMZN MKTP US*1V4KI6LV3 09/01 PURCHASE LVNV, -48.20:
[image: 08/15/2022, AMZN MKTP US*1V4KI6LV3 09/01 PURCHASE LVNV, -48.20]

Comment: Are you using `pandas`? Could you provide with a bit of sample data in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can create extra column that contains the information you are grouping upon:

```
test['group_key'] = test['Description'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0])
grouped = test.groupby(['group_key'])
for key, item in grouped:
    print('Key is: ' + str(key))
    print(str(item), '\n\n')
```

**Note** I assumed that description is space separable, and you need only the first word.